# How can I reset the intellisense settings in VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, intellisense, coderush

I've got a fresh install of VS 2008 Standard and I've installed DevExpress DXPerience 2008 with CodeRush! and for some reason, my intellisense decided to half-work.

I have:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

I can type:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.
```

... and intellisense will show none of the members for Person, UNLESS I delete the '.' and type it again. Then it'll work as I always expect it.

This happens among objects/projects/solutions consistently. I'm betting that it's a VS or CodeRush! setting but I'd like to rule out VS before I try to re-install CodeRush! (takes a while).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look at the following settings in your Visual Studio:

1. Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> General -> Statement completion -> Auto list members
2. Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> General -> Statement completion -> Parameter information
3. Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> General -> IntelliSense -> Show completion list after a character is typed
4. Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> General -> IntelliSense -> Committed by pressing the space bar

Are they all activated? If not, please do so.

Comment: +1: Indeed they are all activated, and I checked to ensure that '.' was one of the completion list characters as well. Must be a CodeRush! setting.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, it's a CodeRush setting. Follow these steps to get to the IntelliSense options page:

1. From the DevExpress menu, select "Options...".
2. In the tree view on the left, navigate to this folder:

   Compatibility
3. Select the "IntelliSense" options page.
4. Uncheck the "Suppress IntelliSense acceptance when potential templates exist at the caret" option.

Hope this helps.